# Windows Phone não realiza requisição em API

Tags: windows-phone-8-1, asp.net-web-api, http-request, mvvm

Bem, possuo os seguintes módulos no meu projeto:

- Concerts.Console
- Concerts.Mobile
- Concerts.Core
- Concerts.Models
- Concerts.WebClient
- Concerts.Tests

Basicamente é o seguinte: O módulo *Concerts.Core* utiliza os módulos *Concerts.WebClient*, para realizar as requisições, e o *Concerts.Models*, para servir os models na hora da deserealização (todos os módulos são PCL).

Quando testo os métodos do *Concerts.Core* no Concerts.Console, eles funcionam normalmente. Mas quando testo no módulo *Concerts.Mobile*, eles agem de uma maneira estranha, sendo esta, onde eles travam a *UI* (os métodos que realizam as requisições, presentes no módulo *Concerts.WebClient*, são assíncronos). E mesmo quando eu os executo em uma *thread* separada, ocorre a mesma coisa. E também não lançam nenhuma *exception*.

[image: Ele apenas termina algumas threads]